# find maximum value of a parameter within an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in the following format, which I got via the following code:

```
echo print_r($list);
```

The array is:

```
Array ( 

[0] => Array ( [id] => 105 [id_parent] => 1 [title] => Pellets [id_product] => 129 [product_name] => AKZ Premium EnPlus A1 Pellets [manufacturer] => AKZ [id_location] => 105 [id_category] => 5 [unitmeasurment] => kg [weightvol] => 15 )

[1] => Array ( [id] => 102 [id_parent] => 1 [title] => Firewood [id_product] => 114 [product_name] => Eucalyptus Crate [manufacturer] => Dalby Firewood [id_location] => 102 [id_category] => 2 [unitmeasurment] => m3 [weightvol] => 1.8 ) 

[2] => Array ( [id] => 102 [id_parent] => 1 [title] => Firewood [id_product] => 118 [product_name] => Eucalyptus Bulk Bag [manufacturer] => Dalby Firewood [id_location] => 102 [id_category] => 2 [unitmeasurment] => m3 [weightvol] => 0.75 ) 

)  1
```

What I would like to do is to get the maximum value for the parameter weightvol` within this array.

I have tried:

```
echo max($list, 'weightvol');
```

and

```
echo max($list['weightvol']);
```

But something is saying to me that `max()` isn't the correct function to use in this case. Can anyone help me out here.

Comment: Mark please post that as the answer and thanks a million for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo max(array_column($list, 'weightvol'));
```

if you're running PHP >= 5.5.0;

```
echo max(array_map(
    function($value) {
        return $value['weightvol']; 
    },
    $list
));
```

for earlier versions of PHP